# body não fica com o tamanho total da página

Tags: html, div, body

Estou fazendo um site(Trabalho de ETEC), meu professor pediu pra usar apenas HTML e CSS, sou iniciante, estava tudo perfeito até eu resolver adicionar mais coisa no site, ele cria barra de rolagem normal mas fica todo desalinhado porque as tags html e body não preenchem as áreas de todas divs, não sei nem explicar, só quero que alguém me ajuda.[image: O site continua mas a tag body e html não]
https://codepen.io/BrowGabriel/full/MMEzJK

Comment: "não sei nem explicar, só quero que alguém me ajuda", meio difícil ajudar se não consegue explicar. Tente elaborar um [mcve] que reproduza o problema reduzindo todo o ruído do código que não tem relação com a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara comece colocando estes css, tirando a Navbar e o footer o resto do seu body vai dentro da tag main, procure usar vh ou % em vez de px. O vh deixa o tamanho que você definiu igual em telas maiores ou menores.

```
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main{
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer{
  position: static;
  background-color: #2c5d88;
  bottom: 0vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```